# Update JSF só funciona no formulário todo (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, hibernate, primefaces, java-ee, xhtml

boa noite.
Estou quebrando a cabeça com um problema que parecia simples

Tenho um formulário com alguns campos, ao selecionar um combobox eu quero esconder e exibir alguns campos.
Estou usando o 'p:ajax'para executar o update.

E nos campos à se esconder, estou usando 'rendered'.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente se eu executar o comando:

```
<p:ajax update="frmCad" event="change" />
```

Essa prática não é legal pq sempre reseta todos os outros campos que já estarão preenchidos.Porém, se eu setar o campo especifico para atualizar, ele não faz nada. No caso seria:

```
<p:ajax update="pam:lblSexo" event="change" />
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Em resumo, meu código é o seguinte:

```
<h:form id="frmCad" prependId="false">
  <p:accordionPanel id="pam" multiple="true" activeIndex="0,1">
    <p:tab id="tbCad" title="Cadastro" >
      <h:panelGrid id="gp1" columns="3" columnClasses="primeiraColumnP">

      <h:outputLabel id="lblSegPessoa" for="id" value="Pessoa: " styleClass="estilolabelCampos" />
      <p:selectOneRadio id="optTipo" value="#{pessoaBeanView.objetoSelecionado.pes_tipo_pessoa}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Física" itemValue="Fisica" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Jurídica" itemValue="Juridica" />
        <p:ajax update="pam:lblSexo" event="change" />
      </p:selectOneRadio>

  <p:outputLabel id="lblSexo" value="Sexo: " rendered="#{pessoaBeanView.objetoSelecionado.pes_tipo_pessoa == 'Fisica'}" />

...fechamentos>
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Seu Bean é ViewScoped? Acredito que é de Request, por isso os outros campos são resetados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O update só vai funcionar se o componente `lblSexo` estiver renderizado. Tente fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
(...)

<p:ajax update="pnlSexo" event="change" />

(...)

<h:panelGroup id="pnlSexo">
    <p:outputLabel id="lblSexo" value="Sexo: " rendered="#{pessoaBeanView.objetoSelecionado.pes_tipo_pessoa == 'Fisica'}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo,
O objeto só pode ser exibido se for renderizado  na inicialização.
Como o painel havia sido, ele carregou normalmente. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.